# How can I add eventListener to all objects that have the same class in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have multiple text fields on the stage and I want to add an eventListener to all of them at once without having to assign an instance name to each of these text fields. Can I do this by simply adding an eventListener to the TextField class so that every text object can have this eventListener?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have your TextField on the main stage, you can do it this way:

```
 for (var i:int=0; i<this.numChildren; i++) {
      var do:DisplayObject = this.getChildAtIndex(i);
      if (do is TextField) {
           do.addEventListener (yourListener, yourCallback);

      }

 }
```

Comment: Doesn't this need some kind of recursion to get nested children?

Comment: He wrote he has them on the stage, but I'll edit my answer thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have TextFields going on and off the display list, you could do something like adding a listener for `ADDED_TO_STAGE`. This event doesn't bubble, so you'll need to set the `useCapture` flag to true.

The listener could look something like:

```
protected function onAdded(e:Event):void {
   if (e.target is TextField) {
       e.addEventListener(someEvent, someFunction);
   }
}
```